# Как используя fetch() передать заголовок при запросе?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, angular2, ecmascript-6

При попытке выполнить запрос к серверу - заголовок не отправляется.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <title>Devpage</title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
  const myHeaders = new Headers();
  myHeaders.set('Authorization', 'Basic dXNlcjpwd2Q='); // user:pwd
  fetch(
    'http://tihonv.pythonanywhere.com/', {
      method: 'POST',
      mode: 'no-cors',
      headers: myHeaders,
    }).then((resp) => console.log(resp));
</script>
```

При отправке запроса - заголовки [не отправляются](https://habrastorage.org/files/cbe/aa0/d37/cbeaa0d37d134f00a7f9f54f63f7f7b7.png).

Проверить можно отправив запрос [сюда](http://tihonv.pythonanywhere.com/)

Comment: Firefox 51.0.1
Chrome 56.0.2924.87
NodeJS 7.6.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вообще-то `Authorization` и `no-cors` — вещи взаимоисключающие. Вы сами запретили передавать логины-пароли, вот и не возмущайтесь теперь ;)

Чтобы передать-таки этот заголовок, надо всё-таки поставить `mode: "cors"`.

В вашем случае, если вы всё это делаете в пределах одного сайта, этого должно быть достаточно, чтобы заголовок `Autorization` был передан.

---

Ниже рассматривается случай, когда сайт, который отправляет запрос, и сайт, который его принимает — разные сайты. Кроссдоменные запросы — более сложная штука. (example.com — сайт, на котором запускается `fetch`, yourserver.com — сайт, куда отправляется запрос)

При отправке такого кроссдоменного запроса браузер в первую очередь отправит OPTIONS-запрос серверу:

```
OPTIONS / HTTP/1.1
Host: yourserver.com
Origin: http://example.com
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Access-Control-Request-Headers: authorization
```

На это ваш сервер должен ответить, что он разрешает передавать вот это вот всё, причём разрешает это всё именно тому сайту, который отправляет запрос (Origin):

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: authorization
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://example.com
(альтернатива:) Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

И только уже потом браузер, когда получит разрешение на отправку от сервера, отправит настоящий POST-запрос с этим несчастным `Authorization`:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: yourserver.com
Origin: http://example.com
Authorization: Basic dXNlcjpwd2Q=
```

И при ответе на POST-запрос yourserver.com всё ещё должен не забывать указывать, что он разрешает сайту example.com заниматься этим:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://example.com
(альтернатива:) Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

Если вы упустите хоть что-нибудь из этого, ваш `fetch` не заработает. Вот такие параноики современные браузеры

Comment: Добавил в настройках сервера заголовки.

Теперь застрял на том что сервер [при ответе](https://habrastorage.org/files/c86/739/16e/c8673916ea774fdfa0727abbf336ff01.png) на OPTIONS отправляет 401. Куда ещё можно посмотреть? Не хочется прокси создавать для того, чтобы всё на одном домене находилось.

Comment: @Tihon чинить сервер, чтобы возвращал не 401, так как это неправильное поведение

Comment: Увы нет кода от модуля, который работает с логикой. Значит - прокси?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй так

```
const req_url = 'http://localhost:5000/'
let resp = fetch(req_url, {
method: 'POST',
mode: 'no-cors',
headers: {
  'Authorization'              : 'Basic dXNlcjpwd2Q=',
},

}).then((resp) => resp)
```

Comment: Не работает. Не отправляет заголовок. [Пруф](https://habrastorage.org/files/de6/1db/1dc/de61db1dc04643638abbc2bd9ca809eb.png).

Comment: @Tihon а в вашем варианте заголовок уходит?

я у себя использую let headers = new Headers();headers.append('Authorization', 'Basic MTAxaW50ZXI6dGVzdDEwMQ=='); и всё ок

Comment: Проверил все три способа. Заголовки не уходят.

Comment: @Tihon isomorphic-fetch используешь?

Comment: Скорее всего - да, во всяком случае он есть в node_modules, дополнительных телодвижений не делал и ставил [react-redux-starter-kit](https://github.com/davezuko/react-redux-starter-kit.git). Как проверить?

Comment: @Tihon require('isomorphic-fetch'); есть?

Comment: Нет. Но при добалении _import 'isomorphic-fetch'_ или при вызове _require('isomorphic-fetch')_ - заголовки также не передаются.

Comment: Всё работает (справа код отправки в методе render) http://dropmefiles.com/2ilmS

Comment: Не работает. [Сниппет](https://gist.github.com/TihonV/7b3b1036bb208321c1031166daef6e51).